# Installing dll file into GAC by drag and drop

Tags: visual-studio, dll, gac

I had build and compile a class project in Visual Studio, I would like to deploy the dll file into Global Assembly Cache (GAC) by drag and drop.

My question is...

1) Is there any side effect of drag and drop of dll into GAC instead of using gacutil.exe?

2) After installing of dll into GAC, I required to do iisreset in order my class project to take effect, why?

thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I use drag and drop and it's fine for me.

2) No, iis reset is not needed, but you have to restart application pool, where dll used.

Comment: is it you mean recycle the iis pool?